# Remember me for 1 hour in android application

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I am working in an android application and I want to implement **Remember Me** functionality for a particular time in my android application. I used shared preference to save these values but how can I delete my values in shared preference after a particular time period say for example 1 hour or is there any other method  to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

To start with, go through [this sample project](https://github.com/rakeshcusat/Code4Reference/tree/master/AndroidProjects/AlarmManagerExample)

Answer (score 0):

This is for clearing the sharedpreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedDelete = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedDelete.edit().clear().commit();
```

And take look at `AlarmManager` or `Handler` or `Timer` for doing this delete after 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

They should help you~